# how to provide initial data for QuerySnapshot<object?>?

Tags: flutter, dart

here is my code :

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthService _authService = AuthService();
    return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(
      initialData: ,
      value: DataBase('ydhjvhjvjhbvyrduychkch').brews,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
          elevation: 12,
          title: Text('Brew Crew'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: () async {
                await _authService.signOut();
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.brown[800],
              ),
              label: Text(
                'log out',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.brown[800]),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i have no idea what to ptovide here as i am a beginner in statemanagement ...please help me find a solution to thsi problem ...

here is also my database file:

```
class DataBase {
  DataBase(this.uid);

  late final String uid;
  // collection refrence
  final CollectionReference brewCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('brews');

  Future updateUserData(String sugars, String name, int strength) async {
    return await brewCollection.doc(uid).set({
      'sugers': sugars,
      'name': name,
      'strength': strength,
    });
  }

  //get brews stream
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> get brews {
    return brewCollection.snapshots();
  }
}
```

Note :  i have used provider 5
Note : just trying to work with firestore and provider package.
i appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Note that you don't have to provide an initial data. Is there a particular reason why you want to provide it, or you're just following a tutorial that does it?

Comment: thanks for your attention ...im following a tuturial and at this level i have created a stream of Query snapshots to be notified of every changes that happens and the instructor is now using sreamProvider but he doesnt provide the initial data as it want required in 2019 in provider package BTW here is the link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10PcEkQsF9Y    if you have any replacement that works let me know ..